# If cell contains string "---" delete another cell

Tags: excel, vba, string, contains

I'm a beginner in VBA.

This is my table:

[image: table]

I want that the cell "€ Sell" on the total rows to be the sum of its "€ Sell".

I already have this macro that finds empty cells and sums the values on top of it until it finds another empty cell. This is the macro:

```
Sub SumFam()
'
' SumFam Macro
' Soma familias
'
' Atalho por teclado: Ctrl+o
'

FirstRow = 1
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
EmptyCell = 0

For RowX = FirstRow To LastRow

    If Cells(RowX, "M") = vbNullString Then
        StartCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(FirstRow, EmptyCell)
        Cells(RowX, "M").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R" & StartCell & "C13:R[-1]C13)"
        EmptyCell = RowX + 1
    End If

Next RowX


End Sub
```

The problem is, this table is exported using sql and I'm not able to make the cells on the total rows to appear empty, so I'm trying to delete this cells.

The macro i tried is this one:

```
Sub Delete()

Dim i As Long

i = 1

Do While i <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text, "---", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Range("M", i).Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

For some reason, it is not deleting.
Can someone help? 
Thank you all.

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire row? or just clear that cell? If you just want to clear the cell, do `...Range("M",i).ClearContents`.  To remove the whole row, `...Range("M",i).EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: ^ `Range("M" & i)` - and  you should delete starting from the bottom row up.

Comment: I want to delete just the cell, to make the first macro work.
`Range("M",i).ClearContents` also did not work

Comment: Use `&` and not `,`: `Range("M" & i).ClearContents`. Or delete if needed - but if deleting you need to loop from the last row to the first one. Or just use a Filter here.

Comment: Ok, now I have this:`

`Sub Delete()

Dim i As Long

i = 1

Do While i <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text, "---", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Range("M" & i).ClearContents
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop

End Sub`

And still nothing happens.

Comment: Keep out: if you want to delete rows for whatever reason, you can never go from beginning to end, you should always go from end to beginning (start with `i=CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` downto 1), otherwise you might risk missing some.